# How to pass req, res to callBack function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

In node.js, how to pass req, res for callBack function?

for example,

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    var content = '';

    fs.readFile("./json/hello.json", function(err, file)
    {
        if(err)
            res.render("index", {
                json: content
            });
        else
        {
            content = JSON.parse(file);
            res.render("index", {
                json: content.name
            });
        }
    });

});
```

It works well. But the code is hard to look because of lot of indentation. So I want to do like this.

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile("./json/hello.json", root_readFileCallBack());

});
function root_readFileCallBack(err, file)  {
    if (err) {
        res.render("index", {
            json: content
        });
    }
    else {
        content = JSON.parse(file);
        res.render("index", {
            json: content.name
        });
    }
}
```

Code above is better to read. But this makes error that cannot find "render" from "res" variable.

I tried to pass req, res as parameter but it doesn't work well.

How can I pass req, res to callBack fuction?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Append req/res arguments to the callback function.

```js
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile("./json/hello.json", root_readFileCallBack.bind(this, req, res));

});
function root_readFileCallBack(req, res, err, file)  {
    if (err) {
        res.render("index", {
            json: content
        });
    }
    else {
        content = JSON.parse(file);
        res.render("index", {
            json: content.name
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: res/req still not defined in `root_readFileCallBack`

Comment: @JaromandaX Whoops, you are correct, I misread the code...

Answer (score 3):

Create a closure function, the function will return a callback function for `readFile` function, and the function's param is `res` object.

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  fs.readFile("./json/hello.json", root_readFileCallBack(res));
});

function root_readFileCallBack(res) {
  return function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
      res.render("index", {
        json: content
      });
    }
    else {
      content = JSON.parse(file);
      res.render("index", {
        json: content.name
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: With the arrow function syntax, you can do it with less indentation: `const root_readFileCallBack = res => (err, file) => { ... }` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

@hoangdv has a great answer that's commonly used in practice. Creating factory functions like that is a useful trick to learn.

Here's another way to go about achieving what you want.

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    const callback = (err, file) => root_readFileCallBack(err, file, res)
    fs.readFile("./json/hello.json", callback);

});
function root_readFileCallBack(err, file, res)  {
    if (err) {
        res.render("index", {
            json: content
        });
    }
    else {
        content = JSON.parse(file);
        res.render("index", {
            json: content.name
        });
    }
}
```

Basically we make root_readFileCallBack() take a res parameter, then in router.get() we wrap root_readFileCallBack to modify its behavior a bit - specifically, we'll cause res to get passed in automatically whenever our new callback is called.

This is using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), but a normal function would work just fine too.