# Why does this code throw a reference error?

Tags: node.js

So i tried using the file system with the http server, first i tried using anonymous callback functions and it ran, then i tried using named callback functions.

What i expected it to happen is to write from the html page to the server:

```
const FileSystem = require("fs")
const Http = require("http")

function ManageServer(req, res) {
  FileSystem.readFile("index.html", ReadFileFunc)
}

function ReadFileFunc(err, data) {
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"})
  res.write(data)
  return res.end()
}

const server = Http.createServer(ManageServer).listen(8080)

setTimeout(() => {
  server.close()
}, 10000)
```

but instead of doing that it threw a reference error saying that res is not defined.

Comment: The error says exactly what the problem is: `res` is not defined in the scope of `ReadFileFunc`. You have defined `res` as argument to `ManageServer`, so it is a variable scope issue. Move `ReadFileFunc` inside of `ManageServer`, after call to `readFile` to make it work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65351049/how-to-pass-req-res-to-callback-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reach `res` from within `ReadFileFunc()` as it's a function argument for a different function that isn't a parent function so you can't reach it.  You can either move `ReadFileFunc()` inside of ManageServer or you can pass `res` to ReadFileFunc.

**Option 1: Move ReadFileFunc code inside of ManageServer**

```
function ManageServer(req, res) {
  FileSystem.readFile("index.html", (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.statusCode = 500;
          res.end();
          return;
      }
      res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"});
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
  });
}
```

**Option 2: Pass `res` to ReadFileFunc**

```
function ManageServer(req, res) {
  FileSystem.readFile("index.html", (err, data) => {
     ReadFileFunc(err, data, res);
  });
}

function ReadFileFunc(err, data, res) {
  if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.end();
      return;
  }
  res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/html"})
  res.write(data);
  res.end();
}
```

Comment: I have a question: what do you mean by parent function?

Comment: @IWannaAskQuestions - In my first code block, you see the function ManageServer.  Then, you see where it calls `FileSystem.readFile()`.  And, the 2nd argument to calling `FileSystem.readFile()` is an inline callback function.  When that callback gets called, then the "parent function" I refer to is the `ManageServer()` function.  You can access its arguments from within the callback function.

Comment: I'm really curious about the "err" thingy and what happens if it gets ran

Comment: @IWannaAskQuestions - It sends an empty http response with a 500 status (which is an error status).  You're free to decide what to send there, but the point is you have to communicate an error back to the client.